# A 'Required' Collection field could not be updated via `AddOrUpdate`

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I'm using Asp.net web api 2 + entity framework 6.

Basically I have 2 models:

```
public class MyOrderModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string OrderNumber { get; set;}
    public string AuthCode { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public List<MyOrderDetailModel> Details { get; set; }
}

public class MyOrderDetailModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount{ get; set;}
}
```

After ran the *Package Manager Console* command `Enable-Migration`, in `Configuration.Seed(WaynyCloudTest.Models.ApplicationDbContext context)`, I was trying to add some pre-loaded data:

```
context.MyOrderModels.AddOrUpdate(
    s => s.OrderNumber,
    new MyOrderModel
    {
        OrderNumber = "0001",
        AuthCode = "ABCDE",
        Details = new List<MyOrderDetailModel>()
        {
            new MyOrderDetailModel()
            {
                Amount = 5.67M
            }
        }
    };
```

After the first(initial) `Update-database` command, everything is fine and I can see above data persisted to database 2 tables.

Later, I want to update the `AuthCode` property value from `ABCDE` to `ABCDEXXX`,
the only change is the value assignment:

```
context.MyOrderModels.AddOrUpdate(
    s => s.OrderNumber,
    new MyOrderModel
    {
        OrderNumber = "0001",
        // THE ONLY CHANGE!
        AuthCode = "ABCDEXXX",
        Details = new List<MyOrderDetailModel>()
        {
            new MyOrderDetailModel()
            {
                Amount = 5.67M
            }
        }
    };
```

I would expect the EntityFramework will find the target data row in database by searching condition on `OrderNumber` and then update the `AuthCode`, but now I always got this exception in `Seed` function:

> Entity Validation Failed - errors follow:
>
> MyTest.Models.MyOrderModel failed validation
>
> - Details : The Details field is required.

Obviously the value was supplied for field `Details`, so what I've missed?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the `Id` field of `PostPayQRCodeFuelOrderModel`. In your environment, the database uses this field as an identity (primary key) field and wants to generate the value itself.

In your case, there is an easy workaround:

```
context.MyOrderModel.AddOrUpdate(
    p => p.OrderNumber,
    new PostPayQRCodeFuelOrderModel
        {
        OrderNumber = "00001",
        Details = new List<MyOrderDetailModel>()
        {
            new MyOrderDetailModel()
            {
                Amount = 5.67M
            }
        }
    }
);
```

Assumably, `OrderNumber` is unique, so this should work fine. In addition, running the seed again will not duplicate this data.

UPDATE:

It is possible to keep the original `MyOrderModel.AddOrUpdate()`, i.e., give the `Id` explicitly:

First, you need to prevent the auto-generation of the primary key value for `MyOrderModel`:

```
public class MyOrderModel
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
```

Then, you need to re-create the `MyOrderModel` table. NOTE: the usual approach of adding a migration just to modify the `Id` field will not work, you need to re-create the table.

Running the seed multiple times works, i.e., there are no duplicates (just checked it myself).

UPDATE 2:

I don't have a full explanation, why your code is not working, but with the code below it should be possible for you to construct the creation and the update of the database objects as you wish.

This code can be run in Seed(), multiple times without duplication. The update of `AuthCode` is, of course, artificial, but my point was to separate the creation and the update (just in case these need to be separated in the final implementation).

The whole project is available in https://github.com/masa67/AspNetNg, branch `SO34252506-1`.

Here's the code:

```
var mom = context.MyOrderModel.Where(m => m.OrderNumber == "00001").FirstOrDefault();
if (mom == null)
{
    mom = new PostPayQRCodeFuelOrderModel
    {
        OrderNumber = "00001",
        AuthCode = "ABCDE",
        Details = new List<MyOrderDetailModel>() {
            new MyOrderDetailModel
            {
                Amount = 5.67M
            }
        }
    };

    context.MyOrderModel.AddOrUpdate(p => p.OrderNumber, mom);
    context.SaveChanges();
}

mom.AuthCode = "ABCDEXXX";
context.SaveChanges();
```

UPDATE 3:

A couple of suggestions, if this is still not working:

1. Consider dropping the `Required` constraint for `Details` and handle the consistency programmatically. I would not use this constraint on navigation properties anyways (but I am only familiar with EF to the extent of how we are using it in our current project at work, so there might be different views on this).
2. Test your code by re-creating the database first.
3. Test my Solution (link above). It is working for me, so there might be a difference in configuration somewhere.
4. Since `Details` is not `virtual`, EF is not using lazy loading. I was expecting this to cause problems, as `Details` becomes `null` when the object is read from the database, but that was not the case in my environment. You might try eager loading, but I doubt if this has any impact:

Eager loading:

```
var mom = context.MyOrderModel.Where(m => m.OrderNumber == "00001").Include(m => m.Details).FirstOrDefault();
```

UPDATE 4:

If this is still not working, then delete the database, but re-create the migrations in addition:

1. Delete the existing migrations.
2. Do not let EF make the assumption that it knows the state of your database, but force it to create the migrations from scratch (see other SO questions for advice). However, BEFORE doing that, please do notice that this operation will most probably overwrite the `Seed()` function as well, so take a copy of that file before the operation.

Comment: why i can't use the `Id` as the primary key?

Comment: You as well are using it as the primary key, but I read your question so that you want to be able to define the `Id` value explicitly. It is possible, see my update above.

Comment: I've taken a test by refer your first snippet of code, change the selector to `OrderNumber` instead of `Id`, still got the same error of `Details` field is required.

Comment: I can have a look at this later today (7 hours from now) and provide you with a copy of the .NET solution I used to test my answer.

Comment: My original solution proposal does work for me. Did you clean up the database (delete the tables) between the trials? Anyhow, here's the full project: https://github.com/masa67/AspNetNg, use branch `SO34252506-1`.

Comment: I've updated the question(basically no code changes), and did the testing on VS, still got the same error, could you help to check again?

Comment: I've tried your latest code, still got the same error.

Comment: UPDATE 4 added. Something is missing in the guidelines, because also I had to do a lot of trialling before getting rid of the error message related with `Details`. I hope it is the migrations part.

Comment: I don't think this is the problem of db, the error is poped up from application, i did the profiling in db, the `Updating` command never send from app.